# XSLT key() lookup

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying out a sample of look-up tables in XSLT and am not able to get it to work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" />
   <xsl:key name="classification-lookup" match="classification" use="id" />
   <xsl:variable name="classification-top" select="document('')/*/classifications" />
   <xsl:template match="BusinessListing">
      <listing>
         <id>
            <xsl:value-of select="id" />
         </id>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="$classification-top">
            <xsl:with-param name="curr-label" select="." />
         </xsl:apply-templates>
      </listing>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="classifications">
      <xsl:param name="curr-label" />
      <category>
         <xsl:value-of select="key('classification-lookup', $curr-label/listingData/classifications/classificationId)/description" />
      </category>
   </xsl:template>
   <classifications>
      <classification>
         <id>7981</id>
         <description>Category1</description>
      </classification>
      <classification>
         <id>7982</id>
         <description>Category2</description>
      </classification>
      <classification>
         <id>7983</id>
         <description>Category3</description>
      </classification>
      <classification>
         <id>7984</id>
         <description>Category4</description>
      </classification>
   </classifications>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the source is as below .

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BusinessListings>
<BusinessListing>
    <id>1593469</id>
    <listingData>
        <classifications>
            <classificationId>7982</classificationId>
            <classificationId>7983</classificationId>
        </classifications>
    </listingData>
</BusinessListing>
</BusinessListings>
```

In the result below , The category is empty but I need the Classification Id from the source to be matched with the id in the classification tag and the category generated .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<listing>
<id>1593469</id> -- Empty I need the Category2 and Category3 here
<category/>
</listing>
```

I know that I may be wide off mark but I've just started off with XSLT and referred the sample here http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xsltip.html . Thanks for the help .

Comment: Some of the XML seems to be in the stylesheet.. the `<classifications>` part. Is it supposed to be in the XML document source?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation of some of the problems you have and for a complete solution. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Your XSLT stylesheet contains an error** -- according to **[spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Stylesheet-Structure)**, any child-element of `xsl:stylesheet` (aka *top-level element*) must be in a non-null namespace:

> "*In addition, the xsl:stylesheet
>   element may contain any element not
>   from the XSLT namespace, provided that
>   the expanded-name of the element has a
>   non-null namespace URI. "

If the XSLT processor you are using doesn't raise an error, then it is non-compliant and buggy and shouldn't be used. Find and use a compliant XSLT processor (I am using .NET XslCompiledTransform, Saxon 6.5.5, ..., etc).

There are other errors, too.

**Solution**:

1. Define a new namespace with prefix (say) "x:":
2. Change the embedded `<classifications>` to `<x:classifications>` -- now this conforms to the Spec.
3. Perform more changes to the code until you get this transformation:

   ```
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:x="my:x" exclude-result-prefixes="x">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="classification-lookup" match="classification"
            use="id" />

       <xsl:template match="BusinessListing">
           <listing>
               <id>
                   <xsl:value-of select="id" />
               </id>
               <xsl:apply-templates/>
           </listing>
       </xsl:template>

       <xsl:template match="classificationId">
        <xsl:variable name="vCur" select="."/>
           <xsl:for-each select="document('')">
            <category>
               <xsl:value-of select=
               "key('classification-lookup',$vCur)/description" />
            </category>
           </xsl:for-each>
       </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/> 

    <x:classifications>
       <classification>
           <id>7981</id>
           <description>Category1</description>
       </classification>
       <classification>
           <id>7982</id>
           <description>Category2</description>
       </classification>
       <classification>
           <id>7983</id>
           <description>Category3</description>
       </classification>
       <classification>
           <id>7984</id>
           <description>Category4</description>
       </classification>
    </x:classifications>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
   ```

   .4. In the above code notice the line: `<xsl:for-each select="document('')">` .

The purpose of this is to make the stylesheet the current document. The `key()` function operates only on the current document and if you want the embedded `classification` elements to be indexed and used, you must change the current document (usually in this way). In XSLT 2.0 the `key()` function allows a 3rd argument which is a node from the document whose index should be used.

**When this transformation is applied to the provided XML document:**

```
    <BusinessListings>
        <BusinessListing>
            <id>1593469</id>
            <listingData>
                <classifications>
                    <classificationId>7982</classificationId>
                    <classificationId>7983</classificationId>
                </classifications>
            </listingData>
        </BusinessListing>
    </BusinessListings>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<listing>
   <id>1593469</id>
   <category>Category2</category>
   <category>Category3</category>
</listing>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick guide. I was using Oracle(Sun's) Transform class for this transformation and it didn't throw any error . I'm pretty naive about this - I'll check this out deeper . Thanks again ..

Comment: Have come across a strange issue: Everything's fine when the XSLT is processed from the XSLT file but the lookup does not happen when I receive the XSL as a String and try the transformation. I have the issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356083/xslt-lookup-using-key-when-xslt-source-is-processed-from-string-in-java . Thought you may be able to give a tip. Thanks again !